# which tensorflow API should i use to make this tensor?

Tags: tensorflow

Suppose there is a tensor `A=[[1, 2], [2, 3], [4,5]]`

I want to make new tensor based on `A`

`A' = [[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [2, 3], [2, 3], [2, 3], [4, 5], [4, 5], [4, 5]]`

Which tensorflow API help me to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Tensorflow has tile method for repeating values of tensor over some axis. The method accepts a tensor and list which represents number of repetition for each axis.

```
A = tf.constant([[1, 2], [2, 3], [4,5]])
A_ = tf.reshape(tf.tile(A, [1,3]),[-1,2])

A_.eval(session=session)
#array([[1, 2],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 2],
       [2, 3],
       [2, 3],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5],
       [4, 5],
       [4, 5]])
```